# Can't Start Ubuntu 10.04 What steps to take?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

Installed Ubuntu 10.04 and was happy with how it was working. Then I tried to restart.... After restart, Ubuntu wouldn't start. It doesn't even get to the "ubuntu" loading screen with th e5 little dots that light up under the logo.

The screen just goes black and, actually, looks like the power to the monitor is shut off. Finally got it to run off a live CD. I had to burn a new CD and burned it at super slow speed (only 4X) because the old CD wasn't working. I read somewhere that burning slower helps improve CD quality. Anyway, thanks to the live CD, I can post here, but I have no clue what to do next.

Comment: Since you can boot the live CD, can you mount the hard drive and post the contents of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`?

Comment: WHERE CAN I UPLOAD THE CONTENTS OF xorg.0.log?????

Comment: Not sure if anyone is reading this, but I'm not convinced it's a video card issue. When I get the blank screen and inevitably hit the power (off) button, the Ubuntu loading screen (with the dots lighting up) appears just before the machine shuts down.

Comment: You can upload the log to http://pastebin.com/ and link it, or if it's small enough, just put it in the post.

Comment: I am sorry to say, but http://ubuntuforums.org/ may be able to help you better, especially at the thread named `Installation & Upgrades`: http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive removed Ubuntu from my machine and am now running Fedora 13. Stable as a rock!

Answer (score 1):

Can you hit the escape key and get more details?  I know with some versions of Linux you can hit Esc and it shows you the printout messages of the bootup process.  This will help you know if a particular process has stalled.

Answer (score 1):

Determine the make and model of your computer (if it's a laptop this will be even easier), and if your system is nonstandard, your display adapter. Search [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/search.php) or [Google](http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=lucid+boot+problems&qscrl=1) with this information.

You may find the issue is related to plymouth, the boot process in general, or driver issues for your device. If the issue is common enough, a quick scan of the [Ubuntu Bug Tracker](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bugs) will locate the best workaround.

Answer (score 0):

There are several causes to the blank screen on 10.04 startup, most of which have to do with video configuration.  My own Dell has an Intel Extreme Graphics video that "became" unsupported with 10.04, but I found instructions on how to switch on the support.  Here're are a couple of links that may help.

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-fix-ubuntu-10-04-lts-lucid-blank-screen-at-startup.html
http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2010/05/06/ubuntu-10-04-lucid-blank-screen-at-startup-workaround/

Comment: thanks for the links. I don't understand this part:

Comment: Add this to the end of the command line:

i915.modeset=0 xforcevesa

Comment: The i915.modeset command controls the behavior of the intel driver, while `xforcevesa` forces the system to use a backup driver, which has few features but works on almost all hardware.